# Exposing DataAccessLayer in WCF services

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, nhibernate, ninject

I've builded an N-Tier application for CRUD operation with 3rd party libraries.
This is my app design packaging:

List item

- **Core** - with domain models and entities.
- **DataAccessLayer**  - with 3rd party libs NHibernate and IOC container Ninject
- **Ui** - Wpf app or Asp.net MVC app

Now i want to separate UI from DAL, exposing my CRUD repositories via WCF Tcp services.
This choice was made for client-server design:

- **Server**: WCF -> DAL with all 3rd party softwares for Database Connection (a lot of driver are very bigs and expensive to install in 100+ clients).
- **Client**: My WPF or SilverLight UI.

I've builded MVC and WebForms APP, a lot of people think that this is a better solution!

But with wpf I have many possibilities to play with graphics and development is faster for me.

All my repositories extending an Interface (for Dependency Injection with Ninject) and i want to add this to my WCF services without create others Interfaces. A lot of my repo's function returning list of NHibernate objects, how to add Attribute "DataMember" to a non WCF project?

But my simple question is, "WHAT IS THE BEST WAY OF DOING THIS,maintaining a good design?"
Thanks for patience!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want all of your business logic in the WCF service with the UI as dumb as possible. That way you can create any number of User Interfaces (WPF, Silverlight, MVC, iPhone even) and they are all small and simple with all the common logic in the WCF.

You need to keep things as loosely coupled as possible so following on from that you don't want to pass database things to the front end. Instead you want to send POCOs or DTOs to the front-end that do just enough for the job. Avoid sending a whole database item to the front-end because ideally your front-end should have no knowledge of what database is being used or how it is structured.

As far as your UI is concerned ONLY the WCF contract is important and the DTOs etc. The WCF should be split into several different layers (or tiers), this depends on your approach but you could have facade, business logic, data access layers (do some research into what fits your situation best). You might want to use repository pattern etc, etc, but that will be in the WCF service and the UI will have no knowledge of what is happening in this "Black box".

Ultimately what you want is for all the components to fit together with the least amount of "coupling" where you should be able to swap one component out for another without everything else "depending" on it and breaking.

This is a **DEEP** subject and I have scratched the surface but hopefully get your thoughts on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, i want to write this in my code :-) Can you suggest me where i can find code example for this DEEP subject?